# What element do you need to create an autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I want to create a highly customised autocomplete feature - hence none of the existing libraries suit my need.

I am wondering what element do you use to create the drop down part of an autocomplete feature, is it a floating div or something like that. Once I know that, the rest is easy.

Answer (score 1):

well, it must be a container that can be styled in a manner that suites your needs(mainly : `position absolute/relative` ,`display:block` and a fixed width).I mean that it can be a `div` or it can be an `ul`, but you cannot make it work with a `span`.
I would go with the ul to keep it simple, but if you need some advanced styling (such as a border with shadow), you may need to wrap that ul into one or more divs.The javascript doesn't rely on the type of element that you use.

Comment: How do you make a div or li float --- so that it doesn't "push' the other content away. Is it some kind of floating property that needs to be set?

Comment: My mistake, autocomplete doesn't make things "float" they still "push" the other content.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of different elements are possible. I'd suggest an absolutely positioned `ul`.